# Prove the following using mathematical induction

Tags: induction

Prove using mathematical induction that $n<3^n$ for all positive integers $n$

I came until here, 3^k+1< 3^(k+1)

I wanna know if this is already the final answer?

Comment: Please show what you've done to attempt this problem. Also, please use mathjax for formatting. I added mathjax to this question.

Comment: @grefpet nisbet. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it true for n=1? Yes. Suppose true for $n$ and show this implies it's true for $n+1<3^{n+1}$. Then we have the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 n<3^n\\
\Rightarrow n+1<3^n+1< 3^n+3^n+3^n \quad\text{Since n>1}\\
=3\cdot3^n=3^{n+1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}